# m4 does not obey expansion?

Tags: preprocessor, m4

I use m4 for a little text preprocessing here, and it behaves in a way I don't understand.

This is the portion in question:

```
ifdef(`TEST',
    define(`O_EXT', `.obj'),
    define(`O_EXT', `.o'))
```

This macro will *always* be expanded to `.o`, regardless whether `TEST` is defined (m4 -DTEST) or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quoting the other arguments to `ifdef`. Try this:

```
ifdef(`TEST', `define(`O_EXT', `.obj')', `define(`O_EXT', `.o')')
```